# Writing EPS images into PDF using FPDF with PHP

Tags: php, fpdf, eps

Im using FPDF library to generate PDF files and my requirement is to write `.eps`/`.ai` files into PDF file, for that Im using `EPS/AI` extension for this FPDF(http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/1092/)

but when implement it in my code it is showing Error as

> FPDF error: No BoundingBox found in EPS file: my_eps_file.eps

my PHP code is

```
$pdf->ImageEps('my_eps_file.eps', 15, 70, 20);
```

I have some text writing functions also in same file, if I remove this eps file writing statement everything is working fine, so I can say there is nothing wrong with library inclusion, but something is going wrong in EPS flow, can some one please help me, thank you.

Comment: Is this even supported in FPDF? I have been searching through the class file for that method, and I don't see it --- at least in the new releases?

Answer (score 0):

This function uses "ereg", that is deprecated. You must replace ereg with preg_match.

Replace this line

```
ereg ("%%BoundingBox:([^\r\n]+)", $data, $regs);
```

With this one

```
preg_match("/%%BoundingBox:([^\r\n]+)/", $data, $regs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also replace the line:

```
$lines = split ("\r\n|[\r\n]", $data);
```

with the function **preg_split**:

```
$lines = preg_split ("/\r\n|[\r\n]/", $data);
```